# Image parameter on ssrs report

Tags: image, reporting-services, parameters

Im looking into the option of converting some excel based reports that we use into an ssrs based reports. These reports need to have different text and images on then each time which is why it hasn't been done before.

Ive looked at using text boxes to submit text into certain locations on the report so it can be changed each time which works fine, but id like to do the same with pictures also as depending on who sends the report we may want to add a picture on them with their signature for example.

Again I was thinking of having various image parameters and the user can select the image they want but I have no idea how to set parameters that put an image onto the report or if there is any way of having a browse button to locate the image or if you have to submit a url to the images location.

Any advise or links to articles would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image you can Embed, External, Database.

Below is option to use External image. The example below will have a parameter in the report to allow the user to select the image

1. Upload images to report server

[image]

2 Create parameter in your report. You can find lots of examples out there to create parameters.

[image]

The value in the  Report Parameter Properties is the image location in report server.

[image]

In Report Designer - Image object - Set Properties

[image]

[image]

Deploy the report to report server to test the image display

Comment: Thanks I did this in the end, realised I needed a image folder on the report server and then called the image from there.